# Can iOS 7 app get rejected due to custom popup?

Tags: iphone, applications, ios, app-store-connect

I've submitted my first app to Apple and waiting for approval.

I've created a custom popup and used it within my app. The popup looks similar to alert view. Below is the screenshot. Are there any chances of app being rejected because of this?

[image]

Comment: You had two questions in here. This site works better when there is only one question per question. That way, it's easier for other people to find solutions if they have the same problem. I've edited out your second question, but feel free to ask it separately.

Comment: OK @patrix. I'll keep it in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen various apps with their own system. I don't think they will decline or deny you app for having it customized as there are many different kinds of views around.

It's not your pop-up is doing something it shouldn't as just displaying info, with an option to click something, right?